# load properties file depends on spring profiles

Tags: spring-profiles

I want to use  PropertyPlaceholderConfiguration to load different property file depends on spring.profiles.active passed when web application launched. I have different stages divided by two groups. read application.properties when spring profile is 'prod', otherwise read application-dev.properties file.

When I launched non-prod stage, the developmentPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer() called, "Development properties read" print out, I guess application-dev should be loaded. But When I use @Value("${aws.key}") to read the value, it's application.properties' value.

I don't know what's wrong

Forgot mention I use spring-boot.

I did little test, let's say I have two same properties name in both file. aws.key=dev in dev file aws.key=prod in default file. Even if I active dev stage, the aws.key=prod in application.properties was always read in. But, If I remove 'aws.key' in application.properties, then aws.key=dev was read in. I think the appliaction-dev.properties file was read in, then spring boot read application.properties again override the same properties even if I do not want spring boot to read application.property in non prod stage. how to solve it?

```
@Configuration 
public class PropertyPlaceholderConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @Profile({"test","qa","demo","dev","AWS","localhost"})
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer developmentPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        System.out.println("Development properties read");
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        configurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(Boolean.TRUE);
        configurer.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("application-dev.properties"));
        return configurer;
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("prod") // The default
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        System.out.println("Production properties read");
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        configurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(Boolean.TRUE);
        configurer.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("application.properties"));
        return configurer;
    } }
```

Comment: Seems spring boot doesn't do this way. I place @PropertyResources on Application class to let spring boot to pick up properties file according to spring.profiles.active value, application-{profile}.properties.

Comment: SpringBoot doesn't need to follow this way. -Dspring.profiles.active=prod will set the profile as prod and you can pull the corresponding property file from classpath with the name application-prod.properties.